# Creating jquery 3 step sign up

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, registration

I am looking for the best solution to create a 3 step sign up process on 1 page. I am currently using jquery cycle, and the techniques being used in version 1.3.2 do not work when telling it to slide, it seems to work only in 1.3.1, there is also a issue of the size, slide 3 is much longer than slide 1 and the height it generates is too tall with dead space.

Does anyone know of a simple jquery solution? Can the UI tabs work in this case?

This is what I am currently using

I would like to find a shorter way to do somethings and and perhaps not use cycle.

```
$('#signup-content').cycle({fx: 'scrollHorz', timeout: 0, speed: 300, after: onComp, startingSlide:0});
    $("#createAccount").validate({
        meta: "validate",
        errorElement: "em",
                errorClass: "error",
        validClass: "success",
        highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).closest("div.required").removeClass(validClass);
            $(element).closest("div.required").addClass(errorClass);
            $(element).addClass(errorClass);
        },
        unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
            $(element).closest("div.required").removeClass(errorClass);
            $(element).closest("div.required").addClass(validClass);
            $(element).removeClass(errorClass);
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            if (element.attr("name") == "month"
                 || element.attr("name") == "day"
                    || element.attr("name") == "year" )
             error.insertAfter("#year");
            else
            error.addClass("hide");
        },
        debug:true,

        groups: {

            birthday: "month day year"
        },

        rules: {

            firstname:{required:true},
            lastname:{required:true},
            email: {required: true, email: true},
            confirm_email: {required: true, equalTo: "#email"},
            password:{required: true},
            confirm_password:{required: true,equalTo: "#password"},
            zipcode: {required:true, min:5},
            month:{required:true},
            day:{required:true},
            year:{required:true},
            gender:{required:true},
            agree:{required:true}

        },
        messages: {
        month: {
            required: "Month Is Missing"
        },
        day: {
            required: "Day Is Missing"
        },
        year: {
            required: "Year Is Missing"
        }

        },


         submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
             beforeSubmit:  showRequest,
             success: showResponse
            });
   }
})

function showRequest(formData, jqForm, options) {
    // formData is an array; here we use $.param to convert it to a string to display it
    // but the form plugin does this for you automatically when it submits the data
    var queryString = $.param(formData);

    // jqForm is a jQuery object encapsulating the form element.  To access the
    // DOM element for the form do this:
    // var formElement = jqForm[0];


    alert('About to submit: \n\n' + queryString);

    // here we could return false to prevent the form from being submitted;
    // returning anything other than false will allow the form submit to continue
    return true;
}


function showResponse(formData) {

    $('#signup-content').cycle(1);
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 300);
    $('#message-container').addClass("notice").append('<h3>Your Account Has Been Created!</h3><a href="javascript:;" id="close"><img src="/assets/images/close.png" alt="Close" title="Close"/></a>');
    $('#message-container').fadeIn(1200, function(){
    $('#close').click(function(){
        $('#message-container').fadeOut(1200);

    });

    });
    return false;

}

     $('#goback-step2').click(function(){
          $('#signup-content').cycle(1);
         $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 300);
         return false;
     });
     $('#goto-step3').click(function(){
          $('#signup-content').cycle(2);
          $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: '0px'}, 300);
          return false;
     });

     function onComp(curr, next, opts){
          var index = opts.currSlide;
          if (index == 0){
               $('#step1').removeClass('complete');
               $('#step1').addClass('active').siblings('li').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
          }
          else if (index == 1){
               $('#step1').addClass('complete');
               $('#step2').removeClass('complete');
               $('#step2').addClass('active');
               $('#step3').removeClass('active').addClass('inactive');
          }
          else if (index == 2){
               $('#step2').addClass('complete');
               $('#step3').addClass('active').removeClass('inactive');
          }
     }
```

Comment: As an aside, you may want to use the jQuery form validation plugin to validate your inputs. http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/

Comment: if you validate your input with javascript, make sure you also validate it server side!

Comment: I am, step 1 is doing the validation with the plugin you mention, and on success right now it goes to cycle next slide, and thats where for whatever reason 1.3.2 doesn't like it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use show()/hide() or fadeIn()/fadeOut() combinations with three separate DIV containers for the different form sections.

You could then have a button in each section bound to perform a fade-out/fade-in for the next section:

```
<div id="section1">
  <!-- form here -->
  <a href="#" id="step2">step2</a>
</div>
<div id="section2" style="display:none">
  <!-- drag drop here -->
  <a href="#" id="step2">step2</a>
</div>
<div id="section3" style="display:none">
  <!-- search here -->
</div>
```

**jquery:**

```
$(function() {
  $('#step2').click(function() {
    $('#section1').fadeOut(function() {
      $('#section2').fadeIn();
    });
    return false;
  });

  $('#step3').click(function() {
    $('#section2').fadeOut(function() {
      $('#section3').fadeIn();
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a nice 3-part wizard demo [here](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/multipart/) that uses jQuery Validation. The validation part is not required to use the approach, but a little client-side validation can be really helpful. The bottom of [this](http://jquery.bassistance.de/validate/demo/) gives some other approaches too.