# Multiple form with php mysql and jquery using tabs

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

am newbie to jquery..I have a three steps registration form in which the user have to finish the first form before get the other form till the final step in registration. Is there a way i could accomplish this using jquery tabs? am using codeiginter with mysql..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an excelent article that describes how to set up a step-by-step-form using JQuery:

http://brenelz.com/blog/building-a-jquery-step-by-step-form/

There is also an answer to a simmilar SO question:

[Creating jquery 3 step sign up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1579370/creating-jquery-3-step-sign-up/1579407#1579407)

Though they both don't make use of JQuery tabs, I guess it would still fit your needs.

Comment: i found this, its a great jquery plugin, u might need to try it  http://www.jankoatwarpspeed.com/post/2009/09/28/webform-wizard-jquery.aspx